# Running particular named junit 4.8 tests in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, junit4

I am using junit 4.8 and intellij 8 and i would like to only run tests inside the IDE which are named something like *UnitTest.java.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution with cpsuite. http://www.johanneslink.net/projects/cpsuite.jsp

Pitty it's not in the maven repo.

```
import org.junit.extensions.cpsuite.ClasspathSuite;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(ClasspathSuite.class)
@ClasspathSuite.ClassnameFilters(".*UnitTest")
public class UnitTestSuite {
}
```